# Unity Networkserver.SpawnwithclientAuthroity doesn't work on host

Tags: unity-game-engine

I followed a Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afz2An4X0vw on how to use Unity networking.
The point is to have an object with a network ID component spawn the player and in order to control the player we need to give the client spawning the player authority over that player.

However, having done exactly the same as in the video, whenever I host the game (with the unity Network HUD) the hasAuthority returns false instead of true on only the host.

It returns true on all the other clients (as it should).
To me it seems as if the hosting person doesn't see itself as a client but only the server, yet this doesn't happen in the video linked above.

How do I make the hosting player return true on hasAuthority as it refuses to do so with the code below?

The script on the object (spawned when the client connects):

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ThePlayerScript : NetworkBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject abigail;
    public GameObject abigailN;

    void Start () 
    {

        if(isLocalPlayer == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        CmdSpawnPlayer();
    }

    void Update () { }

    [Command]
    void CmdSpawnPlayer()
    {
        abigailN = Instantiate(abigail);
        NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(abigailN, connectionToClient);
    }
}
```

The code on the player that is spawned by the gameobject:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Abigail : NetworkBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject mainCamera;
    Vector3 myLocation;
    Vector3 cameraView;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        if(hasAuthority == false)
        {
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }
        mainCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
    }
}
```

(I removed the Update function in the Abigail class as it is irrelevant as it doesn't get executed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that hasAuthority in this case will only return false in the Start() method. If you use it in the Update() method it will return true properly if you assign authority simply as you do in "ThePlayerScipt" with:

```
NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(abigailN, connectionToClient);
```

Hope that helps :)